# Complex solutions of equations in Maple

Tags: maple

Is it possible to compute all complex solutions of the equation
$$
e^z = 1
$$
in Maple?

That is, I need Maple print all solutions $z=2\pi k I$.

What procedure do I have to use?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: As far as I know, Maple cannot solve general complex equations (with the exception of polynomials).

Comment: Nor can it display an infinite amount of solutions.

Comment: Both comments above are completely and utterly wrong: Maple by default works in the complex domain, and Maple can and does easily characterize countably infinite families of solutions by using integer-valued parameters.

Answer (score 5):

It is done by

`solve(exp(z)=1,z,AllSolutions=true);`

The output will be

`2*I*Pi*_Z1~`

The `_Z1` represents some constant, and the tilde implies that there is some assumption on the constant, which in this case means that it is an integer.

`getassumptions(_Z1);`

tells you that it must be an integer.